# prepareForSegue UITableViewController using push

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I'm having some trouble passing data from my UITableView to a UIViewController.  I'm using PUSH in storyboard to go from my Cell to the UIViewController, and everything is working well.  When I select a cell in my UITableView it pushes to the UIViewController and I get a nice back button to return to the UITableView. My problem is passing data to the UIViewController using the PrepareForSegue method ... this is what I'm doing:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowUserDetailSegue"])
    {
        UserDetailViewController *userInfo = segue.destinationViewController;
        userInfo.myLabel.text = @"Hello World";
        NSLog(@"I'm here");
    }
}
```

The label "myLabel" does not change when the UIViewController is displayed.  Any idea why?

I've used prepareForSegue before and have been able to pass data, not sure what I'm missing.

Also, xcode is showing all the proper code completions and there are no errors.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the `prepareForSegue` stage the destination viewController hasn't yet loaded it's view so `userInfo.myLabel` is nil.

Add a new property to `UserDetailViewController`, set that to your string instead and in `viewDidLoad` set it up in your label.